# De-activate an username and regenerate the same in kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

In my application,i want to de-activate the existing user and able to create new user with same username and email address.I know,kohana have set username and email address as unique i created a column called is_deactivated in User table and setting a flag to that.If the user is deactivated,the flag set to zero,else the flag is "1".I written an separate function for validation of unique username and email address with reference to is_deactivated flag.If the flag is "0",validation will ignore the existing username and email address and user able to create new user with same existing username and password.New username is created with same username.After signup,it is taking me to existing de-activated user account, instead of fresh new account.But if i login with same username and password,it is taking me to existing de-activated account.In login,i had validated with this is_deactivated flag with 1.

for creating new user with same username i had commented the below lines from User.php,

```
/var/www/html/zergid/modules/orm/classes/Model/Auth/User.php

public function rules()
    {
        return array(
//          'username' => array(
//              array('not_empty'),
//              array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
//              array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')),
//          ),
            'password' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
            ),
//          'email' => array(
//              array('not_empty'),
//              array('email'),
//              array(array($this, 'unique'), array('email', ':value')),
//          ),
        );
    }
```

Need help to how to login to newly created account and not existing de-activated account.

Thanks

Comment: Is the new account created in the DB??

Comment: @Dieter Yes,i can see new account row in User table,but not able to login/after signup it takes me to de-activated account.

Comment: Then there is most likely something wrong with your code when you do the lookup when a user logs in.. Do you have some code where you validate user login?

Comment: @Dieter i updated the question with my signup controller and login controller,please guide me where i am doing wrong

Comment: Some people eat during lunch hours :) And I've been looking at your code, and I was wondering what $user_isactive = ORM::factory('User')->where('username', '=', $username)->find(); does? You say it is the active account, but I think this is just the first account you encounter that you store, so this could be the original one?

Comment: @Dieter Solved it,please see the answer.

Comment: Ok, nice.. I knew it was a call whe you would get the user, but just didn't know where the file was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user is login to site,it checks the username,password.There i am checking my flag condition.See the code below

```
/var/www/html/Kohana/modules/orm/classes/Kohana/Auth/ORM.php

protected function _login($user, $password, $remember)
    {
        if ( ! is_object($user))
        {
            $username = $user;

            // Load the user
            $user = ORM::factory('User');
            $user->where($user->unique_key($username), '=', $username)->and_where('is_deleted','=',1)->find(); //checking the flag here(->and_where('is_deleted','=',1))
        }
```

Worked!